# I can not initialize responsive filemanager using access_key

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, responsive-filemanager

I want to set up responsive filemanager plugin with ckeditor4.

I've used example usage to initialize plugin with ckeditor from official documentation.

and i need also use access_key for security but it didn't work for me.

Here is my code.

responsive filemanager {config.php}

```
define('USE_ACCESS_KEYS', TRUE); // TRUE or FALSE
```

and client side

```
<script>
                                                CKEDITOR.replace('editor', {
                                                    skin: 'moono-lisa',
                                                    external_filemanager_path:"../../filemanager/",
                                                    filemanager_title:"Filemanager" ,
                                                    filemanager_access_key:"myPrivateKey" ,
                                                    filebrowserBrowseUrl : '../../filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&editor=ckeditor&fldr=',
                                                    filebrowserUploadUrl : '../../filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&editor=ckeditor&fldr=',
                                                    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : '../../filemanager/dialog.php?type=1&editor=ckeditor&fldr='

                                                 });


                                        </script>
```

When i try to browse folders from ckeditor, i get same error
**"Access Denied!"**

Answer (score 0):

This is the best option to do

you need to add another get parameter

akey=myprivatekey

```js
       CKEDITOR.replace('editor', {
      skin: 'moono-lisa',
      external_filemanager_path:"../../filemanager/",
      filemanager_title:"Filemanager" ,

      filebrowserBrowseUrl : '../../filemanager/dialog.php?akey=myprivatekey&type=2&editor=ckeditor&fldr=',
      filebrowserUploadUrl : '../../filemanager/dialog.php?akey=myprivatekey&type=2&editor=ckeditor&fldr=',
      filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : '../../filemanager/dialog.php?akey=myprivatekey&type=1&editor=ckeditor&fldr='

          });
```